# My discord bot gives an error when I try send a message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

So I was writing a basic Discord bot for fun. And I wanted it to count how many times "lmao was said". So I wrote this in Python:

```py
if 'lmao' in message.content.lower():
    aantlmao=0
    await message.channel.send('aantal keer lmao gezegd:', aantlmao, '(sinds de laatste bot restart)')
    aantlmao=aantlmao+1
    print('counted a LMAO')
```

The message translates to: amount of times said lmao: [lmaoCounter] (since last bot restart)

But when I type "lmao" in discord it spits out this error:

```py
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site->packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 51, in on_message
    await message.channel.send('aantal keer lmao >gezegd:',aantlmao,'(sinds de laatste bot restart)')
TypeError: send() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Comment: just a slight improvement: with the current code typing LMAO or Lmao with various capitalisation wont register, make the first line of code: `if 'lmao' in message.content.lower() or 'Lmao' in message.content.lower() or 'LMAO' in message.content.lower():`

Comment: I have tried to type it in different capitalization with just `if 'lmao' in message.content.lower():` and it worked perfectly fine. but I know what you mean because I have written some other programs where capitalisation did matter

Comment: ok its just a side note, i havent come across anything where it dosent matter so i thaught it would be relevant here, just somthing to keep in mind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because you passed 3 arguments (separated by commas) to `send()` in which you can pass only one. You should use [string formatting](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/) to avoid this error:

```py
await message.channel.send(f'aantal keer lmao gezegd: {aantlmao} (sinds de laatste bot restart)')
```

### Edit:

Put your variable before your `on_message` event and add `global` before a variable to make it accessible in and outside your function:

```py
aantlmao = 0

@client.event # you might be using @bot.event - it depends
async def on_message(message):
    global aantlmao

    if 'lmao' in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send(f'aantal keer lmao gezegd: {aantlmao} (sinds de laatste bot restart)')
        aantlmao += 1 # you can use the format you used before. This one is just a little bit better
        print('counted a LMAO')
```

Read [this article](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-local-nonlocal-variables) about global, local, and nonlocal variables.

Comment: okay, it now sends the chat message in Discord, but it doesn't count up. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your counter is always set to 0 before message.channel.send. You need to keep it in another place and persist somehow.

Comment: @Jéa I edited my answer. I hope it fits your needs.